# Rails 3- Nested Object Forms (Reusing Address Model)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this issue.

I have a business model and an address model.  To make things more complicated, I also have a location model.  A business can have multiple locations, but only one mailing address.

Here is a simple object chart.

**Business**
-Name
-MailingAddress

**Location**
-Business
-Name
-Address

I want to reuse the Address model for both the Businesses & Locations.  What do I need to do for this.  If it helps, I'm using MySQL.

First how to I structure the models?  Do I need has_many :location,:business (for Location/Business)?
Then how do I nest the forms for creating addresses into new Business/Location forms.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what aspect of this you want help with. Database structure? Model associations? Views & forms?

Comment: Thanks, clarified what I need help with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll start with some basic model code, then move onto controller, then views.

First the models:

```
#app/models/business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :mailing_address, :class_name => "Address", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mailing_address

  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

#app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  belongs_to :business
end

#app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Now the controller new action:

```
#app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb#new
def new
  @business = Business.new

  mailing_address = @business.build_mailing_address
  3.times do
    location = @business.locations.build
    address = location.build_address
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @business }
  end
end
```

Finally the views:

```
#app/views/businesses/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@business) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :mailing_address do |builder| %>
    <h3>Mailing Address</h3>
    <%= render "address_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :locations do |builder| %>
    <h3>Location</h3>
    <%= render "locations_fields", :f => builder %>
    <%= builder.fields_for :address do |mini_builder| %>
      <h3>Location Address</h3>
      <%= render "address_fields", :f => mini_builder %>
    <% end%>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

address partial:

```
#app/views/businesses/_address_fields.html.erb
<p>
  <%= f.label "Street Address"%>
  <%= f.text_field :street %>
  <%= f.label "City"%>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
  <%= f.label "State"%>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
  <%= f.label "Zip"%>
  <%= f.text_field :zip %>  
</p>
```

location partial:

```
#app/views/businesses/_location_fields.html.erb
<p>
  <%= f.label "Location Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :name%>
</p>
```

There are a couple trickier components in this whole thing.  You have to keep in mind that building a has_one and a has_many child object is a different method in the controller.  Also, you need to define the class properly for the mailing address relationship.

If you wanted populate the business mailing address from a collection of the locations associated with the businesses addresses, then you could add a method in the Business model that did something like this:

```
#app/models/business.rb#possible_mailing_addresses
def possible_mailing_addresses
  Location.where(:business_id=>self.id).joins(:address)
end
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. +1

Comment: The only issue is if you want to select a mailing address from the list of the business locations.  You can define a method that does Location.where(:business_id=>id).joins(:address) though to get the Collection of potential mailing lists.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I am able to create a new business and address object (mailing_address).  I'm having trouble retrieving the mailing_address for a given business.  If I do (in a show view):<%= @business.mailing_address.addressLine1 %>, I get: "undefined method `addressLine1' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: addressLine1 does not sound at all like a valid field for an address model.  It'd likely be @business.mailing_address.address_line_1 .

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the models, you probably want something like this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  has_many :addresses, :through => :locations do
    def mailing
      find_by_is_mailing_address(true)
    end
  end
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  belongs_to :business
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :business, :through => :location      
end
```

... this gives you `my_business.addresses.mailing`.

You'll then want a Boolean column in your `addresses` table called `is_mailing_address`, which you set `true` only on an address which is the Mailing Address for its Business. You should also validate within the `Address` model that only one address `is_mailing_address` for each Business.

I'm afraid I'm not very experienced on nested forms; hopefully someone else can help you out.

**Ruby experts**: I'm sure you could have Business `has_one :mailing_address` using `:through => :locations` and `:source`, but I don't understand what `:source` does. Perhaps you could enlighten us both?

Comment: It's actually a ton easier to just define the relationship between the Business and the Address as has_one :mailing_address, :class_name => "Address".  It allows business.mailing_address to be the main way you interact with the child object.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. I guess it feels a little weird that Business has one Address object directly, via mailing_address, and multiple implicitly, through locations; but yes, that works.